# Charting scatter plots with text in x-axis

Tags: excel, scatter-plot

I need to plot a scatter (or any other) chart. The `X` axis should represent the time slots of the day (`0900-0930`, `1000:1430`, etc.). For each time slot of the day, I need to plot a single/multiple TV shows with their viewership ratings on the `Y` axis.

```
Time Slot  Program Name    Ratings
0900-0930   A               2.3
1000-1130   B               2.4 
1000-1130   C               1.7
1200-1400   D               1.8
```

I can't find any way until now (also tried VBA solution, but none worked).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Select data, Insert > Charts - Column, Clustered Column produces:

[image: SO20969379 example]

Answer (score 1):

What @pnuts said then google watching tv, save an image, Format Chart Area, Fill, Picture or Texture, File... navigate to and select the image

[image]

...too much?

Comment: @pnuts to avoid writing code is the ultimate elegance grasshopper... you say it best, when you say nothing at all